# Suitable Client Server setup for Network Game testing

Tags: networking, jakarta-ee, client-server, lan

I am sorry if my question is obvious, but i need the expert suggestion/views, i want to test my Client/Server game for which currently, i am using localhost same machine for both Client and Server.

that's why i not getting any fluctuation in data and measure idea of performance, and in other parameters, what i wanted to ask to have a real world scenario:

if i create a little network with two computers or

if check that on LAN on which i am or

**ARE THESE THREE CASES (localhost included) ARE EQUIVALENT?** or

I really need to test that on different LANs to have reliable testing data and realistic data,

**How these different network setups will influence the testing process?**

Can somebody please suggest, which could be the ideal way or enough for testing?
which above setup will give me more up and downs in number **with LEAST setup/implementing efforts.**

Note: The game is suppose to play on the LAN but it is capable of more.

Thanks,

Jibbylala

P.S: i m newbie in network stuff so if u used the wrong terms, vocabulary pardon me
emphasized text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to test your application under different situations.  For example, test it using a small LAN where you only have one switch between the two computers.  That will ensure that you can, in fact, connect and play over a simple LAN.  Then, test different LAN connections such as a slow link (turn a network card down to 10 Mbps), on a wireless LAN, and if possible even a larger or corporate-type LAN.  The more testing you can do about different situations, the better.  Testing on just your localhost will not be enough.

Comment: thanks, i would appreciate discussion on one of the above scenarios as i have time constraints testing on multiple/other setups would be  difficult, the reason to ask question is to taking help selecting one, so i create that one setup ,  and then test on that.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest testing on the LAN you are on.  This is the most complex of the three.  Testing on the most complex LAN setup will be the most beneficial because it will expose your application to the most possible problems of the three choices.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  If you are asking if you should test on different LANs, the answer is yes.  My answer above explains my preference for what you should do.

Comment: how will you take this if two computer are like this 132.145.20.145 and server 132.145.20.32, for me it's on same LAN.. DO you have same meanings, what about if my server is on 132.192.67.56 then it will be on d/f LANs.

Comment: That would be Internet communication (or at least multiple LANs connected by a router).  In this case, you will need to do more networking setup on your application side.  You will need to broadcast your server's presence somehow (web address, IP address that is available to the public/other LANs, etc.)

Comment: so you are in favor of this : server is on 132.192.67.56, yeah but it's difficult,so what your stance on this: client 132.145.20.145 and server 132.145.20.32 same LAN,will this be ok or atleast resonable?just talk about this please =)

Comment: Testing on a LAN will give you at least LAN experience for your application.  You will see what issues come up (firewalls, used ports, connectivity issues, etc.)  If you are going to test on a LAN, try to make it as difficult as possible for your application.  For example, try connecting one client to a wireless access point onto your LAN.  This will add some connectivity uncertainty, which is good.  Also, try to go through as many devices as possible.  For example, don't connect through the same switch but different switches if that is an option.  Basically, make life difficult for your app.